# What is the reaction mechanism involved in the ring opening seen in 3,3-diphenyloxiran-2-ide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ethers

I have an epoxide with a negative (-) charge on one of the carbons. In which of the two ways should I open the epoxide? I am not able to understand which one to prefer.

[image]

(The general way I think of these rearrangements and breaking and forming of bonds is by doing heterolytic cleavage and placing (-ve) and (+ve) charges on the carbons the bond's between which I am breaking)

I think there's something wrong with the method in which I am approaching this which is causing this issue. Please help me out with the same.

(I know the general theory for opening of epoxide in case of acid/basic attack)

Comment: Was this the initial question? or was it something different?

Comment: The second way looks good. Note the first way would give you a carbene.

Comment: Count your implicit hydrogens carefully in the first option.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal an intermediate step in a reaction sequence for a problem. Btw, how do you make these sequences digitally?

Comment: @JoshMitchell yeah, that should be highly unstable. Looks like I miscalculated the hydrogens or didn't keep track of them!